# how to auto update a foreign key along with primary key

Tags: php, mysql

table1: customer_details

```
c_id(primary key) AUTO INCREMENT
c_name
c_phone
(innoDB)
```

table2: service

```
si_id(primary key) AUTO INCREMENT
c_id2(foreign key) references customer_details(c_id) on delete cascade on delete update
si_1
si_2
si_3
si_4
si_5
(innoDB)
```

I have written php code to update to insert values to si_1,si_2,si_3,si_4,si_5 of table2(service).

whenever i insert values into table2 through html page am getting an error saying
"error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Below is my PHP code:

```
$value1=mysql_insert_id();
$value2=$_POST['si_1'];
$value3=$_POST['si_2'];
$value4=$_POST['si_3'];
$value5=$_POST['si_4'];
$value6=$_POST['si_5'];



$query="insert into service_initiation(c_id2,si_id,si_1,si_2,si_3,si_4,si_5) values ('$value1','','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: I'm assuming above the `$value1` declaration, you have a query that inserts into the customer details table?

Comment: I'm surprised you were getting a foreign key error. I think you should be getting a syntax error because you have `$value1` in the column list, where `c_id2` should be.

Comment: @bamar yes that has to be c_id2,i have changed it,but agian am getting same error.

Comment: @lee yes but am getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query="insert into service_initiation(c_id2,si_1,si_2,si_3,si_4,si_5) values ('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6')";
```

You should leave `si_id` out of the column list, so that it will be assigned automatically via auto-increment. And you need to set `c_id2` to the ID that was assigned to the referenced table.